# $f(z) =\frac1{z^2-6z+8}$ then Evaluate the following integral: $\oint\limits_{C} u dy +v dx$ where $C$ is $|z|=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $u$ and $v$ be the real and imaginary parts respectively of the function $f(z) =\frac1{z^2-6z+8}$ of a complex variable $z=x+iy$. Let $C$ be the simple closed curve $|z|=3$ oriented in the counter clockwise direction. Evaluate the following integral:
$\oint\limits_{C} u dy +v dx$
$\bullet$  I'm confused whether I can use residue theorem or not? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first find the relation between $\oint\limits_{C} u dy +v dx$ and $\int\limits_{C} f(z) dz$

Comment: @jjagmath $\oint\limits_{C} f(z) dz=\oint\limits_{C} \left(u+iv\right) (dx+idy) =\oint\limits_{C}\left( udx-vdy\right) +i \oint\limits_{C}\left(vdx+udy\right)$.  What to do next?

Comment: $\int\limits_{C} f(z) dz$ is a complex integral, you can use the Residue Theorem on it

Comment: @jjagmath Applying residue theorem $\oint\limits_{C} f(z)dz=-\pi i$. Hence the value of the required integral is $-\pi$. Am I correct sir?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $f(z)=u+iv, dz=dx+idy,$ note that $$udy+vdx=\Im \oint f(z) dz=-\pi$$
The integral has been evaluate by Residue theorem for the pole at $z=2$ as $|z|<3$

Comment: I think that will be $-\pi$. Isn't it?

Comment: The residue at $z=2$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$, so the value of the integral is $-\pi$.

Comment: OH! yes you are right.